# Android WebView loading slow with Headers

Tags: android, performance, webview, header, android-webview

We're loading a `WebView` with headers(which is a must in this case). It would not open without it. We tried all methods of sending headers to `WebView`but this only seems to work. Now the problem is that it is taking 2-3 minutes to open the web content with headers but when the securities are removed on the server level, it opens like a charm. Please suggest a way to open the `WebView`fast.

I tried enabling and disabling hardware acceleration but it didn't help.

Here is our Java code:

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebResourceResponse;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.appiness.beroe.R;
import com.appiness.beroe.utils.FontsHelper;
import com.appiness.beroe.utils.PreferencesHelper;

import java.net.URLEncoder;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class Report extends BaseActivity {

    WebView webView;
    PreferencesHelper preferencesHelper;
    ImageView ivBack;
    TextView tvTitle;

    String flip_book;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report);

        preferencesHelper = new PreferencesHelper(Report.this);

        flip_book = getIntent().getStringExtra("FLIP_BOOK");


        initializeViews();
        stylizeViews();

        tvTitle.setText("");

        // For API level below 18 (This method was deprecated in API level 18)
        webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);


        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }
        else {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {



            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                showAlert("Something went wrong","Ok");
            }

            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

                try {

                    String url = request.getUrl().toString();

                    return getNewResponse(url);

                }  catch (Exception e) {
                    //return null to tell WebView we failed to fetch it WebView should try again.
                    return null;
                }
            }


            private WebResourceResponse getNewResponse(String url) {

                try {
                    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

                    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                            .url(url.trim())
                            .addHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + preferencesHelper.getPref("JSESSIONID") + "; X-CSRF-TOKEN=" + preferencesHelper.getPref(preferencesHelper.csrftoken))
                            .addHeader("JSESSIONID", preferencesHelper.getPref("JSESSIONID"))
                            .addHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", URLEncoder.encode(preferencesHelper.getPref(preferencesHelper.csrftoken), "UTF-8")).build();

                    Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();

                    return new WebResourceResponse(
                            null,
                            response.header("content-encoding", "utf-8"),
                            response.body().byteStream()
                    );

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }

            }




        });


        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);


        webView.loadUrl(flip_book);

        ivBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();

            }
        });
    }


    private String getMimeType(String url) {
        String type = null;
        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);

        if (extension != null) {

            switch (extension) {
                case "js":
                    return "text/javascript";
                case "woff":
                    return "application/font-woff";
                case "woff2":
                    return "application/font-woff2";
                case "ttf":
                    return "application/x-font-ttf";
                case "eot":
                    return "application/vnd.ms-fontobject";
                case "svg":
                    return "image/svg+xml";
            }

            type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        }

        return type;
    }


    private void initializeViews()
    {
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvReports);
        ivBack = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivBack);
        tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    }

    private void stylizeViews()
    {
        tvTitle.setTypeface(FontsHelper.Titillium_Regular(Report.this));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you test on emulator or phone and you have facing same loading time issue in multiple phone ?

Comment: check this - https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: @HareshChhelana We have checked on multiple phones and emulators. The issue is same everywhere.

Comment: @Vishal We tried this too but headers are not getting accepted by Chrome custom tabs